# While loop won't work in java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

My code will not execute the while loop properly, it will only ask for the user input. Where is the error in my code?

```
  int number = 0;

  int maxNumber;
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a positive number greater than 0: ");
  maxNumber = keyboard.nextInt();

     while (number < maxNumber);
     {
        number++;
        System.out.print(number);
     }
```

Comment: Remove that semicolon following your while loop condition.

Comment: The question is not phrased in a way that is asking for an explanation of a specific undesired behavior.   The question is asking for entire solution, which is not appropriate on SO.  Question needs to be narrowed down.

Comment: Sorry for the phrasing error, I'll make sure not to do that again in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
 while (number < maxNumber){
    number++;
    System.out.print(number);
 }
```

Note the misplaced semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a semi colon extra

```
 while (number < maxNumber); ///<----
```

It should be:

```
 while (number < maxNumber){
    number++;
    System.out.print(number);
 }
```